# How to get the object only from array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to achieve this format. As you can see on the output there's a bracket but I want to get only the **'10': ["11/21/2022", "11/25/2022"]** or this one.

```
{
    '10': ["11/21/2022", "11/25/2022"]
}
```

```js
const data = [{
  user_id: "10",
  dates: ["11/21/2022", "11/25/2022"],
}, ];

const output = data.map(({
  user_id,
  dates
}) => ({
  [user_id]: dates
}));
console.log(output);
```

Comment: its not possible to use map to make an array an object, use a for loop or such, `let out = {}; for (let item of data) out[item.user_id] = item.dates; console.log(out)`

Comment: not sure what you meant. `output[0]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do this if the array has just one entry. Otherwise, how would you know which array element to use?

Then just create it directly, `map` creates an array, not an object:

```
const [{ user_id, dates }] = data;
const output = {
    [user_id]: dates,
};
```

Live Example:

```js
const data = [
    {
        user_id: "10",
        dates: ["11/21/2022", "11/25/2022"],
    },
];

const [{ user_id, dates }] = data;
const output = {
    [user_id]: dates,
};
console.log(output);
```

Or without the initial destructuring:

```
const output = {
    [data[0].user_id]: data[0].dates,
};
```

Live Example:

```js
const data = [
    {
        user_id: "10",
        dates: ["11/21/2022", "11/25/2022"],
    },
];

const output = {
    [data[0].user_id]: data[0].dates,
};
console.log(output);
```

Comment: add another item to `data`, is map needed if just picking first item, IMO OP wants `{
    '10': ["11/21/2022", "11/25/2022"],  '11': ["11/21/2022", "11/25/2022"],  '12': ["11/21/2022", "11/25/2022"]
}`  etc

Answer (score 1):

map is returning array again, so if you wanna get only object you can use [0] to access it directly

sth like this :

```
console.log(output[0]);
```

or this :

```
    const output = data.map(({
  user_id,
  dates
}) => ({
  [user_id]: dates
}))[0];
```